# SSMA upgrade makes forms read-only?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ms-access, sql-server-migration-assi

I have a database that I have recently upgraded via SSMA to use SQL Server 2005.  If I open a form that is bound to a table, it will display the data from the table; however, I am unable to edit the form and save the information.  Simply typing in a textbox does nothing.

I have noticed that the Access DB now has extra "tables" that begin with "SSMA$[OriginalTableName[", which appear to be the links to the SQL server, and I am able to view and edit those.  I am unable to edit the original tables, only view them.  I've attempted to modify those "bound" tables to the new "SSMA$", however, multiple errors ensue.

Has anyone experienced this before?  Any ideas or insight would be most helpful.

Comment: What are the connect strings on those SSMA$ tables? That should tell you if those are the links you need to use. To find out, go to the Immediate Window in your front end (Ctrl-G) and type: ?CurrentDB.TableDefs("SSMA$[OriginalTableName]").Connect and hit enter. Or, just browse the MSysObjects table, which includes a column for the Connect string for linked tables.

Comment: They appear to be blank; here's the code:
"?CurrentDB.TableDefs("[SSMA$Contacts$local]").Connect"
gives me a new, blank line with nothing in it.  Ironically, running the same code on the standard "Contacts" table yields this:
"ODBC;DSN=XYZ-Proof;APP=2007 Microsoft Office system;DATABASE=XYZ_Proof_DB;Trusted_Connection=Yes"
I'm now guessing the blank connection is my problem, but I'm not sure how to change/update that?  I appreciate your help.

Comment: That looks to me as though SSMA renamed the original local tables and created ODBC links with using those original names.

Comment: Yeah, I've been able to deduce that much; I'm curious as to why I can't edit them even in Table view.  Interesting tidbit; if I re-create the tables via ODBC, I can view and edit them.  I just wonder if the connection string SSMA uses is readonly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I believe i just figured it out.  If a table doesn't have a clearly defined primary key, the SSMA wizard will created the linked tables.  Access, without a primary key on a linked table, apparently doesn't know how to update it and opts to open said linked table in "read-only" mode.  I was able to reproduce the problem by creating a linked table manually, and then a popup asked me to identify the primary key.  Clicking "Cancel" puts the linked table in read-only mode, but creating a primary key and using that column allows me to work with the table.

Comment: In addition to always having a PK defined (without it on every table you don't really have a database, just a bucket of data), I always include a timestamp field in all my SQL Server tables because this helps Access manage refreshes in bound forms.